# Swift: Dynamicall adding JSON to table cell array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have this code, which grabs JSON info

```
struct cellData {
    let cell : Int!
    let text : String!
    let image : UIImage!
}
```

(struct is at top level before controller class)

```
var arrayData = [cellData]()
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    print(annotationId)
    print(annotationTitle)

    arrayData = [
        cellData(cell : 0, text : annotationTitle, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg"))
    ]

    let pumpsURL = "http://www...." + annotationId

    Alamofire.request(pumpsURL).responseJSON { response in

        if response.result.value != nil {
            NSLog("Success")
            let pumpsJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            let allPumps = pumpsJSON["Pumps"]
            let number = allPumps.count

            for i in 1..<number {
                let pumpName = pumpsJSON["Pumps"][i]["name"].stringValue
                self.pumpNames.append(pumpName)

                self.arrayData.append(cellData(cell : i, text : pumpName, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg")))

            }
            print(number)
            print(self.arrayData) // works

        }
    }

}
```

This is the function that adds data from the array into cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch (arrayData[indexPath.row].cell) {
    case 0:
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstCell
        cell.firstImage.image = arrayData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.firstCellLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].text
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell

    case 1...10:
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("StationPumpCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! StationPumpCell
        cell.pumpImage.image = arrayData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.pumpLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell

    default:
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstCell
        cell.first.image = arrayData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.firstCellLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell
    }
```

All of this works fine. It's when I want to add variables that causes errors.
The problems are that a)

```
cellData(cell : 0, text : annotationTitle, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg")),
```

does not echo into the cell (tried `self.annotationTitle` too), even though it prints. Nor can I add `pumpName`. **Fixed** My mistake, it was commented out in the other ViewController and it wasn't printing either, my bad.

And problem b) I can't figure out how to append cellData, ie.

```
cellData.append[(cell : 3, text : pumpName, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg"))]
```

which I have tried and got error 'cannot convert value to expected argument'. **Fixed** In comments

What is the correct way of a) adding data to the array and b) replacing hardcoded values like "A title" with variables in the array? Ie. starting out with an empty array, appending cell 0 with data, then appending cell 1-X in the for loop with data to create a cell (cell#, text, image) for every JSON object in `allPumps` (by placing the array.append into the for loop).

**Edit:** Now Case 0: works fine, Case 1...10: returns blank cells. This worked earlier, when Cell 1...X were hardcoded.
print(self.arrayData) from debug:

```
[Project.cellData(cell: 0, text: Works, image: <UIImage: 0x174096120>, {375, 667}), Project.cellData(cell: 1, text: Success, image: <UIImage: 0x1702855a0>, {375, 667}), Project.cellData(cell: 2, text: Success, image: <UIImage: 0x17009a090>, {375, 667})]
```

Comment: `append` is work this way `arrayData.append(cellData(cell : 3, text : pumpName, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg"))` Also show the declaration of your class cellData

Comment: This append works, thank you. I have added the cellData struct above.

Comment: Doesn't get your first issue what it is?

Comment: I can now append the cellData in the for loop and after the for loop print arrayData (works great), but for some reason it is returning blank cells 1...X in the tableView.

Comment: Edit your question with your current try so that I can get what you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the `tableView` after you append all the `data` in your array. Also do reload on main thread.

```
Alamofire.request(pumpsURL).responseJSON { response in

    if response.result.value != nil {
        NSLog("Success")
        let pumpsJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

        let allPumps = pumpsJSON["Pumps"]
        let number = allPumps.count

        for i in 1..<number {
            let pumpName = pumpsJSON["Pumps"][i]["name"].stringValue
            self.pumpNames.append(pumpName)

            self.arrayData.append(cellData(cell : i, text : pumpName, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg")))

        }
        //Reload the tableView
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** You have start `for loop` with `1..<number` so you are ignoring the first record of array because array start with `0` index.

Comment: It works! Many thanks.

Yep, for loop from 1 because the FirstCell is 0 (arrayData = [ cellData(cell : 0, text : annotationTitle, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ln-bkg"))]) so I continue with 1.

For a future implementation, is it possible to reload the tableView (and thus JSON data) every X seconds so that the table is updated with fresh data?

Comment: Ok, now I see why I can't use 1..<number, it skips the 0 index. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Fid Welcome mate :)